# javascript Regex question mark (?) not detect

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi all I tried to create some `regex` with random value.

```
var data = "demo purpose?";  **OR**  var data = "demo purpose";
var sentence = "can I put these app as demo purpose?";
var re = new RegExp("\\b(" + data + ")\\b", "g");
console.log(sentence.match(re));   // output ["demo purpose"]
```

In variable `data` have two different value `demo purpose?` & `demo purpose` with only question mark. Both console out are same please any one Give me hint what should i do in these case.

-
Thank you

Comment: And what did you expect? `?` means *1 or 0 occurrences of the preceding pattern*.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript) to see how you can escape regular expression special characters.

Comment: I want as it is if pass `demo purpose?` than output should be `["demo purpose?"]`

Comment: Do your search words start with non-word characters? Do you have to match whole words?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you need to escape `?` (i.e. write `\\?`) or else [it would be interpreted as a quantifier in regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html).

Furthermore, the `\\b` is not really necessary because it tries to match a non blank char in which case there is nothing behind `demo purpose?` so `sentence.match(new RegExp("\\b(demo purpose\\?)\\b", "g"))` would return null.

If you want randomness, use `Math.random`. Make an array and get an random integer or 0 or 1 (with `Math.floor`) as the index.

Comment: `data` value should be comes random and I want it `["demo purpose?"]`

Comment: @stribizhev I only read the title when I wrote down the answer. I've updated it after reading the content.

Comment: @stribizhev I am not a believer in spoon-feeding. I think I have given him enough clues on how to achieve what he wants to do.

Answer (score 3):

In order to pass variables into JS regex when using constructor notation, you need to escape all characters that act as regex special characters (quantifiers, group delimiters, etc.).

The `escape` function is available at [MDN Web site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
function escapeRegExp(string){
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

Note also, that `\b` is a word boundary, and it prevents from matching the strings you need as `?` is a non-word character. If you do not need to match word boundaries, remove `\b`. If you need to check if the search word is a whole word, use `(?:^|\W)` at the beginning and `(?!\w)` at the end and use `exec` rather than `match` to obtain access to the captured group 1.

So, your code will become:

```js
function escapeRegExp(string){
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");
}

var data = "demo purpose?";
var sentence = "can I put these app as demo purpose?";
var re = new RegExp("(?:^|\\W)(" + escapeRegExp(data) + ")(?!\\w)", "g");
while ((m = re.exec(sentence)) !== null) {
   console.log(m[1]);   // output ["demo purpose?"]
}
```

If you search for `emo purpose?`, no result will be returned since there will be no match.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
var data = "demo purpose?"; // **OR**  var data = "demo purpose";
var sentence = "can I put these app as demo purpose?";
var re = new RegExp(/demo purpose\?/, "g");
console.log(sentence.match(re));   // output ["demo purpose?"]
```

return ["demo purpose?"],
changing `RegExp("xxx", "g");` to `RegExp(/xxx/, "g");`

You can do

```
var data = /demo purpose\?/; // **OR**  var data = "demo purpose";
var sentence = "can I put these app as demo purpose?";
var re = new RegExp(data, "g");
console.log(sentence.match(re));
```

and you will get the same output