# Regex matching the boundary of a word that may contain punctuation

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am using regular expressions to manipulate a list of space-delimited strings. When a user wishes to delete a tag, the regex replaces the to-be-deleted tag with `null` and the system saves the new list. This ran into a snag when users started entering punctuation as part of the tag (valid use case). I started using regex escape when I realized punctuation was used:

```
RegExp.escape = function(s){
  return String(s).replace(/[\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};
```

When coupled with my existing regex format (`\bTAGTODELETE\b`), this doesn't match in certain scenarios.

Take the following example tag list: `thisisatest? other test test2 test? test?ing`

If I want to delete `test?` from the list, `\btest\?\b` matches `test?ing`. If I want to delete `thisisatest?`, `\bthisisatesttest\?\b` has 0 matches.

I've tried a few iterations but each seems to have its own problems.

Comment: This has aleady been asked. Please [see this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32376884/3832970), and let me know if that helps.

Comment: @stribizhev does not help. Using my test string and your approach has `(?:^|\W)(test)(?!\w)` incorrectly matching multiple items

Comment: I thought you wanted to match `test?`, not `test`. Check out [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eX2uU5/1). It captures just `test?` as a whole word.

Answer (score 1):

Because there isn't a word boundary next to `?`

```
\btest\?\B
```

This would match `test?` followed by sapce not `test?` follwed by `ing` in `thisisatest? other test test2 test? test?ing` input.

`\b` - matches between a word char and a non-word char (vice-versa)

`\B` - matches between two word char or two non-word char.

`?` non word character `space` non-word character. So `\B` is a perfect one for this case.

Comment: This runs into similar problems depending on where the tag is at in the list (beginning, end)

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to work around your current problem with a new regex, but there are probably more headaches in store for you if you stick to this approach. There are better ways to manage tags than concatenating them into a string.

I recommend that you store each tag in an object and represent the tag list as an array of such objects.

Something like this:

```
var tags = [];
tags.push({ text: 'my new tag!', valid: true });
tags.push({ text: 'yeah, dude', valid: true });
```

If a user action causes the `valid` property to be set to false, you can scan the array and splice out the invalid tag.