# JavaScript regex for patterns starting with special characters

Tags: javascript, json, regex, function

This code detects if a regular expression is in a string, and returns them as a JSON string

According to the code, the code does not support for any regex starting with special characters such as (#,@..etc). If i call the function `js_regex(#3[0-9]{2},"#312 hyderabad")` , `#312` is not getting returned as a `rslt`, whereas if I call `js_regex(3[0-9]{2},"312 hyderabad")` , `312` is getting returned as `rslt`

How do I support the patterns for special characters also in the below code?

```js
function js_regex(expr, str) {
  var rslt = "";

  // extract any specific flags
  var flags = "gi";
  if (expr.startsWith("/")) {
    var exprend = expr.length - 1;
    if (!expr.endsWith("/")) {
      exprend = expr.lastIndexOf("/");
      flags = expr.substring(exprend + 1);
    }
    expr = expr.substring(1, exprend);
  }
  if (expr.length === 0) {
    return rslt;
  }

  // only interested in words
  expr = "\\b" + expr + "\\b";

  // run the regex, and save the results as a JSON string
  var re = new RegExp(expr, flags);
  var matches = str.match(re);
  if (matches) {
    rslt = JSON.stringify(matches);
  }
  return rslt;
};

console.log(js_regex("#3[0-9]{2}", "#312 hyderabad"))
console.log(js_regex("3[0-9]{2}", "312 hyderabad"))
```

Comment: I made you a snippet

Comment: It is a usual, frequent issue. `expr = "\\b" + expr + "\\b";` must be something like `expr = "(?:^|\\W)(" + expr.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + ")(?!\\w)"; var matches =[];` and then use `while(m=re.exec(str)) { matches.push(m[1]); }`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32376884/3832970